# Downloading Excel file from Web-page which doesn't appear in source code? - Java

Tags: java, html, excel, jsoup

The link I'm working with is: **https://www.openml.org/t/31**

If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, you should note an "Excel" button which proceeds to download the data into an excel spreadsheet.

I understand how to download a file from a URL using HttpURLConnection but this is a bit different. This excel page doesn't really lead anywhere. From what I found, this download doesn't have a "header" which I can use java.net.URLConnection with nor does it appear in the source code.

I am using JSoup to download some information from the webpage, and one thing I need to download is this excel page - and I've been stuck on this for several days. The "link address" of this download just takes me back to the OpenML homepage.

Although not appearing in the source code, inspect element says:

```
<a class="dt-button buttons-excel buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tasktable" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
```

But this HREF "#" takes me back to the homepage, so I can't use that as the link to download.

I'm fairly new to JSoup and HTML, am I looking in the right place or am I oblivious to some obvious information right in front of me that I'm not seeing?

Is using JSoup even needed in this case? Would Apache be more useful?

Thanks

Comment: It appears to be running Javascript when you click the button. Look into the event handlers on the button.

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks for your reply. I installed visual events 2 and saw there aren't any functions associated with that excel button. I also went to the "sources" tab of Googles dev tools, under "Event Listener Breakpoints" -> Click, there are also no functions. Visual events 2 works exceptionally well on other sites (such as StackOverflow), I am not sure what the issue is with OpenML specifically.